# If I had google fiber's 1GBPS, would uploading a 1GB file via FTP take exactly one second?

Tags: ftp

So if I had google fiber (1GBPS plan) and were to upload a 1 GB file via FTP server, would there be any delay or would it be limited to the download speed of a server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, for several reasons:

1. It's a 1 giga*bit* per second service and you're uploading a 1 giga*byte* file.
2. You're also limited by the server's available inbound bandwidth.
3. The advertised speed is a raw line speed, not a true data speed. Address and control information also has to pass over the line.
4. The TCP protocol that FTP uses can't perfectly fill a line.

Real world reports of people with Google fiber are that they can upload a 1 GB file to a well-connected server in just under 11 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

1 Gbps actually transmits 119.21 MB/s, so no.

And even if it was 1GB/s, it would depend on a couple of factors.

Lag and packet loss have a important effect over the maximum speed of a TCP connection, because each packet containing a couple KBytes of data transmitted have a receivement confirmation. It is very optimized, but depending on the speed and the lag it will most likely always cause delays.

Your bandwidth won't be 100% used for transmitting the file data. Packet headers are a substantial portion of the transmitted traffic, and they will consume part of the bandwidth.

Also, your hard disk cannot read 1GB of data in 1 second, and the receiver probably can't write 1 GB of data in 1 second either.